# insert an indexed new row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with named index and two columns as shown in the picture.

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['system_call','frequency','file_frequency'])
df.set_index('system_call', inplace=True)
```

I want to add a new row if a if-else condition is met.
I tried `df.loc[-1]=[words[0],words[1],1]` but I think it might be for non-named indexes.

expected output-

```
system_call   frequency file_frequency

madvise          300    3
write            277    2
read             23     5
ioctl            45     4
getuid           78     2
epoll_pwait      12     1
futex            13     6
```

as can be seen the last row is added now

Comment: try `df.iloc[-1]=[words[0],words[1],1]`  `loc` is for label based `iloc` is for integer position

Comment: @EdChum but my dataframe has two columns which will include words[1] and 1 and the index is words[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need if `futex` not exist in `index`:

```
df.loc['futex']=[13,6]

print (df)
             frequency  file_frequency
system_call                           
madvise            300               3
write              277               2
read                23               5
ioctl               45               4
getuid              78               2
epoll_pwait         12               1
futex               13               6
```

If exist, row is rewritten:

```
df.loc['madvise']=[130,100]
print (df)
             frequency  file_frequency
system_call                           
madvise            130             100
write              277               2
read                23               5
ioctl               45               4
getuid              78               2
epoll_pwait         12               1
```

If need always add new row use [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) by `Series` with index as columns names and `name` for new index value:

```
df = df.append(pd.Series([13,6], name='futex', index=df.columns))
print (df)
             frequency  file_frequency
system_call                           
madvise            300               3
write              277               2
read                23               5
ioctl               45               4
getuid              78               2
epoll_pwait         12               1
futex               13               6
```

---

```
df = df.append(pd.Series([130,100], name='madvise', index=df.columns))
print (df)
             frequency  file_frequency
system_call                           
madvise            300               3
write              277               2
read                23               5
ioctl               45               4
getuid              78               2
epoll_pwait         12               1
madvise            130             100
```

Comment: will this work if this is the first time entry of index 'futex'?

Comment: Yes, if first time `futex` iot add new row, if exist, row will be rewrite.

Comment: thanks a lot!...do you know how to update the rows in pandas too? i did df.loc['madvise',130]+=int(words[1]) but got error

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - What kind of error? `df.loc['madvise',130] = df.loc['madvise',130] + 10` working? Or `df.loc['madvise',130] += 10`

Comment: Both of them df.loc['madvise',130] = df.loc['madvise',130] + 10 and df.loc['madvise',130] += 10 are giving error..which is TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [32] of <class 'int'>

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - mea culpa, it means `df.loc[index_name, col_name]`, so solution is `df.loc['madvise','frequency'] += 10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171758/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a row in dataframe with specified Index value

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
print(df)
```

[image]

```
df.loc["21"] = {"A":3,"B":3}
print(df)
```

[image]

dictionary with column name and value.
Try this out